# How do I change the gateway of a specific connection using the Mac terminal?

Tags: terminal, network

My goal is to be able to change all of the following for a *specific* device: IP address, netmask, and gateway. So far, I've gathered that I should be able to use `ifconfig con0 10.8.0.14 netmask 255.255.255.252`, but when I try to do `ifconfig con0 gateway 10.8.0.1`, it gets pretty upset and tells me that `gateway` is a bad argument.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The command you're looking for is route.

**Check what your current gateway is**

To check your current gateway, run the command:

```
route -n get -ifscope en0 default
```

This instructs route to return the path it would take using en0 to reach www.google.com.

- The -n argument turns off domain name resolution in the output (else gateway in the sample output below would be the name of my gateway).
- The -ifscope argument limits the query to using en0.  Without it, to OS will select which interface to use.
- default tells route that you want to see the default gateway.  You can put a URL here instead if you suspect your OS is choosing something other than the default gateway to access a host.

The output will be something along the lines of:

```
   route to: default
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: 192.168.1.1
  interface: en0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING,IFSCOPE>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0
```

**Delete the current gateway**

To delete the current gateway from en0, run:

```
sudo route delete default -ifscope en0
```

This will delete the default gateway from en0 while leaving any other defined routes intact.

**Add the new gateway**

To add the new gateway to en0, run:

```
sudo route add default 192.168.1.1 -ifscope en0
```

Replace 192.168.1.1 with the IP address of the actual gateway.

For way more gory details, check out the man page for route.

Comment: So I tried this and it didn't quite work. In the case of trying to do this, my command was `# route delete default -ifscope tun0` followed by `# route add default 10.8.0.1 -ifscope tun0`, the output of both being
`route: writing to routing socket: Network is unreachable` and `add net default: gateway x.x.x.1: Network is unreachable` in that order.